# How do I fix 'return' outside of function when running a Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Being relatively new to [Jest](https://jestjs.io) - and having just used it to good success in a pristine environment/project with no problems, yesterday I decided to give it a shot in an older Node.js environment (10.15.x).

Initially, it worked fine. Then I started pulling in older `requires` dependencies and it immediately started failing:

```
 FAIL  modules/reviews/review.jest.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: /Users/darrin/src/tot/commons/index.js: 'return' outside of function (2:0)

      1 | 'use strict';
    > 2 | return (module.exports = {
        | ^
      3 |       accessControl: require('./modules/accessControl'),
      4 |       about: require('./modules/about'),
      5 |       api: require('./modules/api'),

      at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6325:17)
      at Parser.parseReturnStatement (node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10190:12)
      at Parser.parseStatementContent (node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9877:21)
      at Parser.parseStatement (node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9829:17)
      at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10405:25)
      at Parser.parseBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10392:10)
      at Parser.parseTopLevel (node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9758:10)
      at Parser.parse (node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11270:17)
      at parse (node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11306:38)
      at parser (node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:170:34)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.111s
```

It was news to me that returns at the global level (in these dependencies) aren't strictly okay in JavaScript, but it makes sense. Still... I cannot change these libraries, so how do I get around this error so I can use Jest?

Comment: show the content of _/Users/darrin/src/tot/commons/index.js_

Comment: Hi @MedetTleukabiluly as you'd expect there's a return at global scope. I'm looking for a means to allow this sort of thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, we don't have any interest in waiting for people to 'fix' libraries that return at global scope, so using Jest means I need a way to ignore those.

Here's what I ended up doing:

1. Add a "jest" configuration to file *package.json*:

   ```
     "jest": {
       "transform": {
         "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/.jest.transform.js"
       }
     },
   ```
2. Then in the root directory for the project I created file *.jest.transform.js* and placed this bit to tell Jest to tell [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(compiler)) to allow return outside of functions:

   ```
   const babelOptions = {
       parserOpts: {
           'allowReturnOutsideFunction': true
       },
   };
   module.exports = require('babel-jest').createTransformer(babelOptions);
   ```

I hope this helps someone else - I almost walked away from Jest again because of this little nuance!